# laravel retrieving data from database takes too much time

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am working with laravel project which uses a mysql database.It has some tables which has over 5 million data.it takes too much time to get these data to frontend. following is the function i use to get data. i have some filters used such as date range (from,to) search by name($seach) pagination amount(records_number) etc. but when i try to get all records it takes too much time. is there any solutions/optimizations for this matter?

Thanks.

```
public function transactionListBetween($from, $to, $sort, $search, $records_number, $filter, $previous_sort) {

    $query = $this->accountTransactions
        ->with('transactionType', 'giver', 'recipient')
        ->leftJoin('tbdb_users as recipient', 'recipient.id', '=', 'tbdb_account_transaction.recipient_id')
        ->leftJoin('tbdb_users as giver', 'giver.id', '=', 'tbdb_account_transaction.giver_id')
        ->leftJoin('tbdb_account_transaction_type', 'tbdb_account_transaction.account_transaction_type_id', '=', 'tbdb_account_transaction_type.id')
        ->where('recipient.name', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->select('tbdb_account_transaction.*');

    if($filter) {
        if($filter == -1) {
            $transactionTypeModel = \App::make('App\Models\AccountTransactionTypeModel');
            $depositTypeIds = $transactionTypeModel->whereIn('name', ['PayPal Deposit', 'Eway Deposit', 'Bank Deposit', 'BPay Deposit', 'Poli Deposit'])->lists('id');
            $query = $query->whereIn('tbdb_account_transaction.account_transaction_type_id', $depositTypeIds);
        } else {
            $query = $query->where('tbdb_account_transaction.account_transaction_type_id', $filter);
        }
    }

    if($from) {
        $query = $query->where('tbdb_account_transaction.created_date', '>=', $from);
    }

    if($to) {
        $query = $query->where('tbdb_account_transaction.created_date', '<=', $to->endOfDay());
    }

    if($records_number == 'no_paginate') {
        return $query->orderBy($sort, $previous_sort)
            ->get();
    } else {
        $totalAmount = $query->sum('amount');
        $collection = $query->orderBy($sort, $previous_sort)->paginate($records_number);
        $collection->totalAmount = number_format($totalAmount / 100, 2);
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

[image: laravel debugger screenshot]

Comment: First, are you using indexing on tables?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh yes i use

Comment: You have a model query and a `with` and then 3 left joins. Why not just 4 relationships on the model?

Comment: i didn't get you mate @apokryfos

Comment: I think Eloquent relationship's more slower in this scenario. It is database issue. In my opinion u should get generated SQL from this code and check Execution Plan in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing 3 left joins and getting the same data as you did with the `with`.

You can drop them:

```
public function transactionListBetween($from, $to, $sort, $search, $records_number, $filter, $previous_sort) {
    $query = $this->accountTransactions->->with('transactionType', 'giver', 'recipient')
                ->whereHas('recipient', function ($query) use ($search) { //Query the related model
                     $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$search%"); //Note this will not use an index
                 });

    if ($filter) {
       if ($filter == -1) {            
             $query->whereHas('transactionType', function ($query) {
                 $query->whereIn('id', \DB::raw("(SELECT id FROM tbdb_account_transaction_type WHERE name IN ('PayPal Deposit', 'Eway Deposit', 'Bank Deposit', 'BPay Deposit', 'Poli Deposit')");
             });
       } else {
            $query->whereHas('transactionType', function ($query) use ($filter) {
               $query->where('id', $filter);
            });
       }

    }


    if($from) {
        $query = $query->where('created_date', '>=', $from);
    }

    if($to) {
        $query = $query->where('created_date', '<=', $to->endOfDay());
    }

    if($records_number == 'no_paginate') {
        return $query->orderBy($sort, $previous_sort)
            ->get();
    } else {
        $totalAmount = $query->sum('amount'); 
        $collection = $query->orderBy($sort, $previous_sort)->paginate($records_number);
        $collection->totalAmount = number_format($totalAmount / 100, 2);
        return $collection;
    }

 }
```

This will reduce the main result set greatly making it easier to work with.

Comment: Tried your solution but having same problem mate.

Comment: If removing 3 left joins from the query has not reduced the query time then perhaps the problem is not the query but the actual volume of data you're trying to present

Comment: yes it has over 5 million records. when i try to get few records it works fine

Comment: How is it useful to throw 5 million records to a user?

Comment: its useless to deliver 5Mn. but lets say for 10 000 records. it occurs same problem,

Comment: where's the bottleneck there? How long does the SQL query to get 10 000 records take vs how long does it take to actually prepare the response view?

Comment: it takes between 1-2 ms when i try the query in sequel pro. but on browser it takes almost 25 seconds to display

Comment: how long does it take to transfer the data from SQL to Laravel and then how long does it take for laravel to make a response out of that data? ([laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) can help diagnose these problems)

Comment: attached the screenshot mate

Comment: found the issue mate.Database gives data in less time but after it comes to laravel it takes lot of time to calculate pagination numbers. i used simplePaginate and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have also having this problem when using mysql database. These much records in table with relationship takes too much time. You have to use raw query to get result. You have to use pagination to show the data. because fetching all the data will slow down.

But i highly recommended you to normalize your table structure. In my case i did normalize of my tables by split it with yearly.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why this is happening. it is because of pagination. it takes lot of time to paginate. there are more than 50000 pages so it takes time. i used `simplePaginate() instead of paginate()`. then it loads faster than usual